# Jump/Scroll to selected object in the outliner?

Tags: interface, outliner

How can I jump to the selected object in the out-liner, I've got over 200 objects in my scene, all named cube.___ ... and I can't seem to find my selected object. **How can I jump to it?**

Comment: If you have THAT MANY OBJECTS, consider renaming each cube a different letter and then moving the cube to a different layer. Shove them all back into Active again when done.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> while hovering over the outliner, just like in the 3D view.

Comment: Tiny nit: doesn't have to be `Numpad .`  for me, regular `.` worked just as well.

Just to save time for anyone trying to hunt down the kb shortcut like me ;)

Comment: @pixelpax You are right, both the Numpad . and . is in the keymap.

Answer (score 17):

Another less ideal way is to under the drop down at the top, to select active.

[image]

The down side is that it will hide *everything* else

Comment: I don't see that menu. Blender 2.93.

Comment: @DamnVegetables In 2.93, click filter icon and it is under Objects check box.

Answer (score 4):

Another method I've been finding useful for dealing with the Outliner is to Duplicate the Area Window so it's actually another window.  Now it can be sized up and moved to another screen.  If you only use one screen, you can use Alt-tab to switch between the main Blender window and the Outliner window.  (For OS X, it's CMD+TAB)

[image]
[image]

Now you can split the window multiple times and scroll each one so that you can see(hopefully) everything at the same time with just a glance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is the keymap command you're looking for: `outliner.show_active`

Make a new keymap in the outliner section. I use the same key for Machin3Tools object focus - <kbd>Z</kbd>.