# Possible to click on an object in the viewport and the object list hierarchy automatically goes to that object also?

Tags: interface

I've used Blender for years but have never hopped on the forums. I am still new as I am very slow at this (all self-taught as I know many of us are).

I am sure this question has been asked elsewhere but I couldn't find it so is it possible to have blender respond so that when I click on an object in the viewport the object list hierarchy automatically goes to that object also?

Oh and also -- Seeing as how this is my first post I'll share an image of what I'm currently working on. I've only ever made 3 things before. A potato, a strawberry, and a sculpted demon looking thing that came out by pure mistake. This thing is getting so complex it is time consuming to keep going through the folders in the hierarchy to find the objects.

Anyway here is what I'm currently working on -- A starship hallway - Currently under red alert. I'm using it as a practice model to learn materials and textures. It will eventually have a door at the end of the hallway and you'll see the exterior of the ship and a planet out the port side windows.

[image]

Thank you everyone in advance.

I'll update everyone as this project goes along.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Does this answer your question? [Jump/Scroll to selected object in the outliner?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23789/jump-scroll-to-selected-object-in-the-outliner)

Comment: Yes! Thank you!